# Where is an app filed?

Tags: 20.04, files, desktop-apps

I'm setting up a new install of Ubuntu 20.04. I installed the Zoom Client app. It opens from the Applications window. I want a desktop shortcut for it. Looking for how to do that, I see various methods, but they all require that I find where it is. Navigating the indicated path to Applications, I see nothing with zoom in the name. Likewise when I look in snap packages. Searching for zoom in my files yields no result. Thinking it might not have installed properly, I reinstalled it from the software repository, and again from the Zoom Download Center. I don't see it in my Downloads directory either. Since I can open the app in the Applications window, I know I have it somewhere, but I can't move it to the desktop until I know where to move it from. I am not knowledgeable about computers, and am unfamiliar with much of the terminology. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: if you open `Show Applications` from the 9 dot grid menu on the bottom left of the screen (the dock) you can select it from there. Right click with your mouse and select `Add to Favourites` and it will appear and be save in the Dock for future use.

Answer (score 4):

The applications in the App overview are usually saved  as `.desktop` files depending on how you installed them in either:

- `/usr/share/applications`
- `~/.local/share/applications/`
- `/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/`

Check the file for the `Exec=` line to get the location of the executable:

```
grep '^Exec=' /usr/share/applications/Zoom.desktop
```

Or simply copy it from there and put it to where you like, e.g. `~/Desktop`:

```bsh
cp /usr/share/applications/Zoom.desktop ~/Desktop/
```

Adjust the path accordingly.

---

Alternatively, use the little tool `alacarte` (install via `sudo apt install alacarte`) to check where to find the executable. Find the `Zoom` entry and double click it to see the `Command`.

[image: Application, get Command with alacarte]

(I don't have Zoom installed, so that is just an example image)

Comment: When I tried pasting those commands in a terminal, I was told no such file or directory exists. When I tried installing alacarte, I got: libdvd-pkg: `apt-get check` failed, you may have broken packages. Aborting...
I tried so many different things trying to install the Zoom app that I don't know how I finally installed it. Are there alternative navigation paths than the one given that I could try?

Comment: I finally got Zoom to launch from the desktop. It seems it's in a snap package. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score -2):

Apps installed normally show up in the home directory of the user, depends on how you installed the apps tho, if its through snap it will show up in the ~/snap directory, at least from what I know.